# dynamic images in list view disappear when scrolled down

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

```
   public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private String url;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public ImageLoadTask(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        this.url = url;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

While setting image on a list view, I do this

```
            new ImageLoadTask(courseImageArray[position], ivCourse).execute();
```

In the imageView, the images are being displayed fine when the fragment is launched. But once I scroll down and return back, the images disappear.
Please help, the images disappear when the listview is scrolled down

Here is the code for adapter if needed

```
    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return courseArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Log.e("listView","listview");
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.all_course_item, null,true);
        view1.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        TextView tvCourseName = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.tvCourseName);
        TextView tvHidden = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.tvHidden);
        TextView tvHiddenUrl = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.tvHiddenUrl);
        TextView tvFee= (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.tvFee);
        TextView tvStudentsEnrolled = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.tvStudentsEnrolled);
        TextView tvDuration = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
        if ("free".equals(coursePaidArray[position])) {
            tvFee.setText("FREE");
            tvFee.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            Log.e("Its free","free");
        }
        else {
            Log.e("paid", coursePriceArray[position]);
            tvFee.setText(coursePriceArray[position]);
            tvFee.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        TextView tvRegistered = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.tvRegistered);
        ImageView ivCourse = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.ivCourse);
        tvStudentsEnrolled.setText(numEnrolledArray[position]);
        tvRegistered.setText(courseStatusArray[position]);
        tvHiddenUrl.setText(courseurlArray[position]);
        tvHidden.setText(courseidArray[position]);
        tvCourseName.setText(courseArray[position]);
        tvCourseName.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        tvDuration.setText(courseDurationArray[position]);
        Log.e("img",courseImageArray[position]);
        new ImageLoadTask(courseImageArray[position], ivCourse).execute();
        //Bitmap bmap = getBitmapFromURL(courseImageArray[position]);
       // ivCourse.setImageBitmap(bmap);
        return view1;
    }
}
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong, as I am not able to figure out any method.
Thanks

**EDIT: I used PICASSO library and it worked smooth.**

Comment: I strongly advise you to use some library like Glide or Picasso to handle image downloading in background. However, your async task looks ok. Are you sure there is no expiation when downloading images ? And you should also provide the relevant part of your adapter code (where you create the tasks).

Comment: @sonic picasso worked like a charm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend DO NOT to hold strong reference for any view.
Such kind of a task is pretty complex.
First you should create a `WeakeReference<>` for the image view you are loading image to.
Second thing - i recommend to create a tag for every image you passing to your `AsyncTask`. (Coz position of your view could change).
Try to look at that [link](https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/07/31/loading-caching-and-displaying-images-in-android-part-1/).
There is also a similar post in official android blog, but i can not find it(

Comment: I used picasso and it did the job well